# Finding all group homomorphisms from $(\mathbb{Q},+)$ to $(\mathbb{Q},+)$

Tags: group-theory

I already did it in the case $(\mathbb{Z},+) \rightarrow (\mathbb{Z},+)$, where I verified the action of a homomorphism in the generator of the domain, and it was sufficient to conclude. But in this case I don't have cyclic groups. This is what I observed:

Let $f:(\mathbb{Q},+) \rightarrow (\mathbb{Q},+)$ be an homomorphism  and $q \neq 0$ . Then:

- $f(0)=0$
- $f(-\frac{p}{q}) = -f(\frac{p}{q})$
- If $ p=1$, then $f(q . (\frac{1}{q})) = q.f(\frac{1}{q})$

But I don't know how to merge those informations neither if I'm on the right way. Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $u=\frac pq$. Then $qf(u)=f(qu)=f(p)=f(p1)=pf(1)$ and so $f(u)=f(1)\frac pq = f(1)u$.

Comment: So can I conclude that every homomorphism is of the form $f_{r}(u)= r.u $, where $r=f(1) \in \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @Alnitak, yes... In fact, End$(\mathbb Q,+)\cong \mathbb Q$ as rings.